# mv cannot move file: Text file busy

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Java based REST API that creates an XML file from some data in POST request. I'm using Jackson library for that:

```
XMLMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
file = new File(filePath);

mapper.writeValue(file, someData);
```

Then, i have another Visual Basic scheduled task that is executed each minute, and move this file to another directory. The second process gives me an error: Text file busy. It seems that first process doesn't close correctly the file, and it is blocked.

Is this a bug of this library? What can I do? I'm trying to avoid that the Visual Basic process close the file before move it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include all code that is relevant to handling `file`.

Comment: I'm afraid that I haven't access to VB code. But when I create the file with the code above, I try to move it manually with `mv` command and I get the  error "Text file busy", so I suppose that the error is in the creator process.

Comment: First, from what I can tell, if you are using the newest version of FasterXML, there is no bug. After some searching, I tracked the file write to [line 3433 here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java) Second, it looks like one reason the file might stay open is if it has an issue writing the data, or if it hasn't finished writing the data. When you run your code, are you seeing any errors at all? Lastly, your above comment is confusing.... could you provide more of your Java code having to do with the file?

Comment: @IanM Sorry, maybe I have not been quite clear. I have 2 processes running. I have developed only the first one, in Java. It just creates the XML file. Then, there is a second process (written in VB) that changes the location of this file. The code above is the whole code for create the file. The data is written correctly, since I can open the file and I see all the elements and attributes correctly.

Comment: Odd suggestion, but can you confirm it is the xmlmapper causing the issue: remove the `mapper.writeValue(file, someData);` and see if you can move it, or if the file creation is not closing/completing correctly, I'm thinking you might have to set `file = null` since it may have a handle to the file still.